# ActiveX in WebBrowser in WinForms crashing whole app

Tags: winforms, exception, activex, webbrowser-control

I have a C# WinForms application, that has a WebBrowser control, which loads an html page in which is embedded a 3rd-party ActiveX object, which plays IPTV video.  The Active X supplied by Exterity.  I have also tried the VLC ActiveX control, which was even more unreliable, with the same symptoms.  Same behavior on both XP and Win7.

Intermittently the whole WinForms app exits.  I already handle the ThreadException and UnhandledExcetion events thus:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //set up global exception handling
    Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

These events do not fire before the app exits; and believe me they do work, because they've been in place for a few years now, and have fired many times catching other errors (e.g. timeout database connection) (at which point i restart the whole app)!  I see no entries in Windows Event View.  My exe process just disappears.

I've been reading up on AppDomains, and wondering whether i can put the WebBrowser control in a separate one to the main program/Form; any advice appreciated.

Or are there other ways i can handle, what i presume is, an exception that is going unhandled all the way to the top, at which point the process exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to catch and ignore Access Violations is a recipe for introducing memory corruption that can corrupt your application's data or settings. You'd be better off figuring out *why* the ActiveX control is crashing (e.g. use WinDBG) and addressing that.

Comment: If i could catch the Access Violation, i would happily restart the whole app with Application.Restart().  I would hope that would get me out of further memory corruption in that session; this could lead to perpetual restarts, but that is better than the whole process exiting.

(Cheers for the great fiddler2!)

Comment: I've provided WinDBG logs to the developers of the ActiveX object, and they're 'looking into it'. :-)